# How to update code in gitlab

Tags: merge, gitlab, fetch, pull

My team committed code to gitlab repository and I need to take those updates. I already clone the project into my local directory but didn't take update before.

For taking update what commands need to run. I already tried pull command and it shows the changed file details but that changes are not applying to the project. For apply the changes any new command needs to run again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following commands for taking the update:

```
git fetch && git checkout master

git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global user.name "demo"
git config --global user.email "demo@gmail.com"
```

Create a new repository:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/demo_test.git
cd demo_test
git switch -c main
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin main
```

Push an existing folder:

```
cd existing_folder
git init --initial-branch=main
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/demo_test.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin main
```

Push an existing Git repository:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/demo_test.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```